# Calculate integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have to calculate $$\operatorname{PV}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{y}{1+y^2}dy$$

I ended up with 
$$\operatorname{PV}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{y}{1+y^2}dy=\frac{1}{2\pi}\lim_{a\rightarrow-\infty}\lim_{b\rightarrow\infty} (\ln|1+y^2|)^b_a$$.

How can I proceed? I think this will be $0$, but i need very formal way of showing this..

edit:

hmm it looks like expected value of a random variable with density $\frac{1}{\pi} \frac{1}{1+y^2}$ which is symmetrical, so expected value is $0$. Is that good explanation?

Comment: Do you know any complex analysis?

Comment: yes, residue theorem etc. but indefinite integral seems to be calculated easily

Comment: from residue theorem i see its $0$.. but do we really need to employ complex analysis here?

Comment: hmm it looks like expected value of a random variable with density $\frac{1}{\pi} \frac{1}{1+y^2}$ which is symmetrical, so expected value is $0$. Is that good explanation?

Comment: HINT: The integrand is odd in $y$. So $PV \int f(y) = - PV \int f(y)$...

Comment: If you use the [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) PV$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx = \lim_{t\to\infty}\int_{-t}^{t}f(t) dt$ then its easy as the integral is $0$ for all $t$ (symmetry).